# How to keep SQS message alive when it fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS to hold http requests. How can I keep the message alive (in the queue) to be re-processed when the request fails, without another process grabbing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about **[what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that it's best to ask a question here after you've done your own (re)search on finding an answer yourself; in this way you can then include what you've found so far, and ask a specific question based on what you've tried. Refer also to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098).

Answer (score 4):

The typical process is:

- A message is placed into the **Amazon SQS queue**
- A worker process calls `ReceiveMessage()` to **retrieve a message** from the queue
- The message is **temporarily marked as 'invisible'** (in-flight) so that other workers cannot see the message
- If the worker successfully processes the message, it calls `DeleteMessage()` to **permanently remove the message**
- If the worker does not respond within the *Invisibility Timeout period* (eg if it fails), the message will **reappear on the queue**. The message can then be grabbed by another worker.
- If a Dead Letter Queue has been configured, then a message that is retrieved from the queue more than a defined number of times will be moved to the **Dead Letter Queue** for separate investigation or re-processing.

Your question seems to fit the scenario for using a Dead Letter Queue.